# how do I export/import a variable in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, import, export

How do I export/import a variable in nodejs?

I've tried export and import but it says that its supposed to be a module and when I change the type to module in the json file it says that require is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with CommonJS modules (the Node.js default) you can export a variable by assigning to `exports`, and import it via `require()`:

```js
// bar.js
exports.variable = 'value';

// foo.js
const { variable } = require('./bar');
```

if you're using ECMAScript modules, the keywords `import` and `export` do these:

```js
// bar.js
export const variable = 'value';

// foo.js
import { variable } from './bar';
```

Comment: thank you but its saying ````(node:5404) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)````

Comment: Also I tried console.log(variable) and it says undefined.

Comment: It worked, the problem was that the variable had been uninitialized I guess. Anyways I solved my problem, thank you.